# Converting two's complement output to signed decimal

Tags: c++, decimal, hex, twos-complement

I apologize if this question has been answered already but I have not been able to find what I am looking for.

I am working in c++ with an SPI device.  The SPI device outputs data in 16 bit words in 2's complement form.  I am trying to convert this data into decimal for use with a filter.

I've attached some sample code that asks the user to input a number in twos complement and then outputs the signed decimal version.

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::hex;
using std::dec;
using std::bitset;
int main () {
    uint16_t x2=0;
    cout<<"Please enter the number you would like to convert from 2's complement.  "<<endl;
    cin>>x2;
    int diff=0x0000-x2;
    cout<<"The number you have entered is: "<<dec<<diff<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I run this program and input something like 0x3B4A it always outputs 0.  I'm not entirely sure what is going on and I'm very new to c++ so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.  Also, please ignore anything extra in the header.  This is partof a large project and I couldn't remember what parts of the header go with this specific section of code.

Thanks!

Edit:  This is mostly for Ben.  After reading your most recent comment I made the following changes but am still simply getting the decimal equivalent of the hexadecimal number I entered

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::hex;
using std::dec;
using std::bitset;
int main () {
    int16_t x2=0;
    cout<<"Please enter the number you would like to convert from 2's complement.  "<<endl;
    cin>>hex>>x2;
    int flags= (x2>>14) & 3;
    int16_t value=(x2 << 2) >> 2;
    cout<<"The number you have entered is: "<<dec<<value<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "Conversion" is part of the parsing.  This `0x0000-x2` is not helpful in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard library function `strtol` converts string input to a number, and supports the `0x` prefix as long as you pass `0` as the radix argument.

Since `int16_t` is almost certainly 16-bit two's complement signed, you can just use that.

Comment: Ben, I tried to use int16_t and remove the 0x000-x2 however, I still got the same results as before.  Could you elaborate on how this would work.  Also, I could forsee some trouble with this even if we do get it working because the device will output a 16 bit word, but the twos complement is only contained in bits 0-13 because bits 15 and 14 are flags.

Comment: @user: Then you should pull off the flags: `flags = (input >> 14) & 3`  And propagate the sign bit from bit 13 to bit 14 and 15 to make a full 16-bit two's complement: `value = (input << 2) >> 2`

Comment: Ben, I tried implementing this (see the addition of code in my original question); however, I am still simply getting the value of the hexadecimal input.  That is, inputting 0x3b4a (which should be the 14 bit 2's complement of -1206) outputs 15178.

Comment: @andrew: put it in an int16_t before doing the shift

Comment: Thank you very much for your continued responses Ben.  I thought that I already did store the value in an `int16_t` by initializing `x2` as an `int16_t`.  Is this not the case?

Comment: @AndrewL: Well, serves me right for not testing it.  You need the cast between the left shift and right shift, because the type is automatically promoted to `int`.  http://ideone.com/v28Fmn  So you want `value = int16_t(input << 2) >> 2`

Comment: Thanks so much Ben!! that works exactly how I need it to.  Once again thank you for all your help in what I'm sure is probably something most people should already know!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it is necessary for the OP's question, but for anybody who is just looking for the formula for converting a 16bit 2's complement unsigned integer to a signed integer, I think a variant of it looks like this (for input `val`):

```
(0x8000&val ? (int)(0x7FFF&val)-0x8000 : val)
```

This amounts to:

- if first bit is 1, it is a negative number with all other bits in 2's complement
- extract negative part by subtracting off the 0x8000
- otherwise the lower bits are just the positive integer value

Probably a good idea to wrap this in a function and do some basic error checking (can also enforce that the input is actually an unsigned 16 bit integer).

Answer (score 2):

You asked cin to read as decimal (by making no format changes) so as soon as it reads the x, which is not a 0-9 digit, it stops, leaving you with zero.

Just add `hex` to your cin line: `cin >> hex >> x2;`

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I made this correction and I can now successfully input a hexadecimal number; however, I still cannot seem to get the correct conversion.  For instance, when I input Ox3B4A I now get an output of -15178; however, based upon my understanding of two's complement, this value should correspond to -1206.  Do you have any ideas about why this is happening?  Basically, what I believe I am doing is finding the complement of the number 0x3b4a, which should then simply be the hexadecimal equivalent of the decimal value of the number.

Comment: Now, I know another way I can get this conversion correct, by using the following formula.  dec=-a_(n-1)*2^(n-1)+sum(a_(i)*2^i)_(i=0)^(n-2) where n is the length of the binary representation of the two's complement number, and a_i is the i^(th) term of the binary representation with all written in loose latex format.  The reason i have not used this conversion is because someone told me that it would be very slow compared to other methods and the application I need this for needs to run very fast(again because it's being used by a filter). Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, Mark, Ben was able to help me out the rest of the way but your answer was an important first step! If I could up vote your answer I would.